# AS3: crossdomain.xml doesn't work

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, load, external

I am developping this video player: 
http://www.horsform.com/_WIP/mjf_2011/live/demo_player/_final/index.html

In the exemple above, the player is loading this start image, to display it before the playing of the video:
http://www.horsform.com/_WIP/mjf_2011/live/demo_player/_final/videos/HF_REEL.jpg

--

Here, I then tell the player to load the same image, but on another domain: 
http://www.horsform.com/_WIP/mjf_2011/live/demo_player/_final/index2.html

The given image is: http://www.daviddarx.com/HF_REEL.jpg

--

As you can see, it doesn't work anymore. 
I searched on Google and discovered that I theorically had to add a crossdomain.xml, to make sure that there isn't security protection that avoid swf to load images from other domain.

I so put these two files on my different domains, to tell the swf to accept files from all * domains: 
http://www.horsform.com/crossdomain.xml

http://www.daviddarx.com/crossdomain.xml

But it still isn't working... Do you know what is wrong? Am I missing something? 
Thank you in advance for your help!

Davis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RTE actually tells you what to do:

> A policy file is required, but the checkPolicyFile flag was not set
>   when this media was loaded.

from the AS3 help:

> When you call the load() method of the Loader object, you can specify
>   a context parameter, which is a LoaderContext object. The
>   LoaderContext class includes three properties that let you define the
>   context of how the loaded content can be used:
>
> checkPolicyFile: Use this property only when loading an image file
>   (not a SWF file). Specify this for an image file from a domain other
>   than that of the file containing the Loader object. If you set this
>   property to true, the Loader checks the origin server for a
>   cross-domain policy file (see Website controls (cross-domain policy
>   files)). If the server grants permission to the Loader domain,
>   ActionScript from SWF files in the Loader domain can access data in
>   the loaded image. In other words, you can use the Loader.content
>   property to obtain a reference to the Bitmap object that represents
>   the loaded image, or the BitmapData.draw() method to access pixels
>   from the loaded image.

So you need to pass a `LoaderContext` instance with the `checkPolicyFile` flag set to true as a parameter of the `Loader#load` method

Something like:

```
var loader : Loader = new Loader();
loader.load( new URLRequest( 'http://www.daviddarx.com/HF_REEL.jpg' ), new LoaderContext( true ) );
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for that very effective support! This just works fine: http://www.horsform.com/_WIP/mjf_2011/live/demo_player/_final/index2.html 

By the way, and so that I may be will resolve more problems by myself, what is what you call RTE? Is that something that allow you to see actionscript errors within the browser? Thank you for your help!

Comment: RTE is Run-Time Error which gets thrown when playing the swf. There's also CTE's (Compile Time Error) which get thrown by the compiler when compiling the swf. You can see the RTE's if you install the debug version of the flash player. You can find them here:
http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html